# PMIC with Li-ion charger, stable output and USB OTG?

Tags: power-supply, usb, battery-charging

I am developing small board with MCU, lithium battery and USB OTG and I am wondering what is the simplest way to power up the whole thing?

Basically:

1. If USB cable is connected - PMIC detects type of the charger(from PC
   / wall charger) and charges battery with maximum available current.
   Also stable 3v3 should be provided for MCU.
2. If charger is removed - PMIC supply 3v3 output for MCU.
3. If USB OTG cable connected - PMIC supply 3v3 for MCU and 5v to USB.

So I've found RT9460, which does not provide stable output. External DC-DC is needed.
There is LTC3576 with 3 programmable power outputs, but that's a bit overhead for me.
Maybe there is a simpler solution?

Comment: What about http://www.ti.com/product/BQ24298? or perhaps http://www.ti.com/product/BQ24140?

Comment: Looks good, but neither of this chips can provide stable output voltage - so DC-DC or LDO IC is still needed.

Comment: There is no simplest way. If your expected volume is 10,000 per week, you go with custom PMIC. If less, use TI/Linear/Maxim PMIC and add a DC-DC to whatever voltage you need.

Answer (score 1):

From having a look on Digikey I found the following Texas Instruments part that seems to fit your needs. I found this component by looking in the PMIC(Battery Chargers) section of the Digikey search.

**BQ24090DGQR**

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/BQ24090DGQR/296-38875-6-ND/5143531

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24092.pdf

*(Couldn't leave this as a comment as I don't have enough reputation, sorry.)*

Comment: There is no embedded boost converter for USB OTG, like in RT9460